# Logging scripts from a non-interactive session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've been searching for a way of logging a script that is run in a powershell remote session that is similar to what you get from using `Start-Transcript`. When I try getting a transcript from a remote session, the transcript file gets created, but there is nothing in the file.

```
$servers = "ServerA"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers -Credential $creds -Authentication Default -ErrorAction Stop

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Transcript -OutputDirectory D:\LOGS
    Set-Location c:\scripts
    Get-ChildItem
    Stop-Transcript
    Exit-PSSession
}

Remove-PSSession $session
```

The Transcript file is there, but none of the commands get logged.  I know that this is because the scriptblock that is executed on the remote system is a non-interactive session.

What does everyone else do to log any success / failures in their remote scripts?

Comment: Logs are created on remote machine I assume.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write logfiles on the remote machine. You can collect all information on the caller machine, e.g.

```
$servers = "ServerA"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servers -Credential $creds -Authentication Default -ErrorAction Stop

$result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    #Store result into variable
    $data = Get-ChildItem -path c:\scripts
    #return variable
    return $data
}

Remove-PSSession $session
```

$result on the caller machine will contain the data (objects incl. the hostname of the remote machine) returned from the remote machine.